# Plutus datum and redeemer on cardano-cli

Tags: plutus, cardano-cli, datum, redeemer

I'm trying to deploy a smart contract on cardano-cli after its implementation on plutus playground.

Imagine that I have:

```
data TradeDatum = StartBid | Bid TradeDetails | Offer TradeDetails 
    deriving (Generic, ToJSON, FromJSON)


data TradeDetails = TradeDetails
    { tradeOwner :: !PubKeyHash
    , budId :: !BuiltinByteString
    , requestedAmount :: !Integer
    } deriving (Generic, ToJSON, FromJSON)
```

How can I write this in an example JSON to submit on cardano-cli? I saw an example with int: 42,

```
{
  "constructor": 0,
  "fields": {int: 42}
}
```

but I really don't know.

1. How can I define the different types?
2. Inside the tradedetails, how can I define? and for example, how to express the pubkeyhash?

Can you give me an exmaple? There are some tutorials with the types of data that I can write inside the JSON (like int)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the following source [Cardano-Api Haddock](https://input-output-hk.github.io/cardano-node/cardano-api/Cardano-Api-ScriptData.html#g:1). Here you will find all about the conversion between Haskell data types and the Json format the cardano-cli uses.

I noticed that you used the marketplace of SpaceBudz as an example, so lets have a look at the other code in that repository. Notice the line [99](https://github.com/Berry-Pool/spacebudz/blob/fed5d9051953639d38d70c2c6e6948542787e547/src/cardano/market/ghc/plutus-trade.hs#L99).

```
print $ "Datum value: " <> encode (scriptDataToJson ScriptDataJsonDetailedSchema $ fromPlutusData (Plutus.toData offerDatum))
```

Here that function prints the `offerDatum` defined at line 85. You see here how the function from the cardano-api are used and then encoded to convert the datum to a json form? Here the `<>` symbol just means concatenate the two strings.

For a more detailed explanation of what is going on in this line have a look at the PPP cohort 3 lecture 3 from lars on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABtffZPoUqU&list=PLNEK_Ejlx3x2zxcfoVGARFExzOHwXFCCL&index=6).

Comment: got it. thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

> {
> "constructor": 0,
> "fields": {int: 42}
> }

This isn't valid because `fields` must be an array. The index of the constructor and fields will match the order of types defined for the validator script. For a Bid you'd use constructor 0 with a single field which is a json representation of TradeDetails (bytestring, bytestring, integer).
It is easier and safer to use `scriptDataToJson`.

Comment: got it. thanks :)

Comment: This answer helps me, indirectly. Thanks